# How do i animate BottomNavigationView Menu Item Icon with ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using android support designs `BottomNavigationView` for bottom tab navigation.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:itemIconSize="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/blue_active"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_items">


    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

What i am trying to do is:

**Programmatically animate tab(menu) icon with `ObjectAnimator`**  when it is pressed

This is the menu:

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="@string/nav_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_games"
        android:icon="@drawable/games"
        android:title="@string/nav_games" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/profile"
        android:title="@string/nav_profile" />
</menu>
```

Code:

```
 mMainNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.nav_home -> {

                   //item.icon is drawable
                   var myAnimation =  ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(item.icon,"rotation",0f,360f)
                    myAnimation.duration = 500


                    myAnimation.start()  //nothing happens
                    setFragment(HomeFragment)

                    true
                }
```

With this nothing happens no animation.

What is wrong ? Should i use another way to animate or am i just applying it wrong ?

I tried animating an imageview with icon drawable and then setting it as items actionview but this also does not work.(some reaction happens but produces some unreleated strange behaviour)

```
 var drawable = applicationContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_home)
                    var someImageView = ImageView(this)
                    someImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable)

                   var myAnimation =  ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(someImageView,"rotation",0f,100f)
                    myAnimation.duration = 2000


                    myAnimation.start()
                    item.actionView = someImageView
```

bounty link is broken please check this:
https://streamable.com/99pa8

Answer (score 10):

Try below solution

**Step - 1**

Create **animated vector drawable** using [ShapeShifter](https://shapeshifter.design/) and import this animated vector drawable, into your Android Project from Android Studio and place it in `src/res/drawable`.

**Step - 2**

Create an **Animated State List Drawable** for each of the icon in the bottom navigation view.

**anim_settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-selector xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:targetApi="16">

    <!-- provide a different drawable for each state-->
    <item android:id="@+id/state_on"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_settings_active_avd"
        android:state_checked="true"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/state_off"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_settings_inactive"/>

    <!-- specify transitions -->
    <transition
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_settings_active_avd"
        android:fromId="@id/state_off"
        android:toId="@id/state_on" />

</animated-selector>
```

**Step - 3**

Use this animated state list drawable as icon.

**menu_bottom_nav.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_settings_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/anim_settings"
        android:title="@string/settings"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
...
</menu>
```

**Step - 4**

Set this **menu_bottom_nav.xml** as **menu** for bottom navigation view.

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_tab_selector"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_nav"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        app:elevation="0dp"/>
```

Now Run the android application on your device and check the bottom nav bar animation.

For more details please prefer [this](https://medium.com/@naththeprince/delightful-animations-in-android-d6e9c62a23d3) link.

I hope this can help you!

Comment: Can this be used to make this animation? Notice the icon translation. https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0vZQ.gif

Comment: @Dr4ketheb4dass may be you can do that using this way but I am not sure.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me, cause the icon would use a wrong state after onResume. Looked like it used a final frame of animation.
So I used static drawables for states and animated drawables for transitions.
Here is a reference file of some dude on gitgub https://github.com/mchllngr/android-animated-selector/blob/master/app/src/main/res/drawable/asl_download.xml